# Problems with results when using betweenness with igraph

Tags: igraph

I am currently having problems with the results when using betweenness in igraph. 
I have created the following network (which is a star network with node 1 in the center)

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
rv <- c(2,3,4,5,6)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,rv))
```

Then I calculate the betweenness for each node and add it to a dataframe:

```
g3=graph.data.frame(df, directed=TRUE)
bFrame<-as.data.frame(as.table(betweenness(g3)))
```

The problem is: if you use directed=FALSE you will get that node 1 has a centrality of 10 which makes sense. If you on the other hand use directed=TRUE I get that 1 has a centrality of 0.

In consequence I have two questions:
 1. Why is the centrality in the second condition 0?
 2. Shouldn't it be 2* the value of the undirected condition? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality

Thanks in advance
Pavel

Comment: There are no directed shortest paths going through `1`, so it's betweenness is zero.

Comment: Ah ok. So its only a path  if two consecutive edges don't point to the same node.

I changed the code to this and I got a value != 0
    id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2)
    rv <- c(2,3,4,5,6,1)
    df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, rv))
    g3=graph.data.frame(df, directed=TRUE)
    bFrame<-as.data.frame(as.table(betweenness(g3)))

Thank you